# JSON for Modern C++ _json Syntax

Tags: c++, json, user-defined-literals

[JSON for Modern C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) uses the following syntax:

```
json j = "{ \"happy\": true, \"pi\": 3.141 }"_json;
```

and I was wondering how they are accomplishing this.

I don't understand the string literal _ json syntax.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

Comment: Using Raw string would be a good addition: `R"({ "happy": true, "pi": 3.141 })"_json` :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++11 added [user defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) to the language. Defining a user defined string literal would look like so:

```
MyType operator"" _my_udl(char const*, std::size_t);
```

It works almost exactly like a regular function call. When you have `"some string"_my_udl`, the compiler generates a call to your `operator"" _my_udl` with the string literal and size passed in.

This is what Niels Lohmann's json library is doing with `_json`; it's a UDL that is equivalent to a call to `json::parse`.

Answer (score -1):

On the docs for [JSON for Modern C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json):
(serialisation / deserialisation)

Note that without appending the _json suffix, the passed string literal is not parsed, but just used as JSON string value. That is, json j = "{ \"happy\": true, \"pi\": 3.141 }" would just store the string "{ "happy": true, "pi": 3.141 }" rather than parsing the actual object.

Basically, if you don't put __json at the end, there's no way for the compiler to know that you're intending to store this as a JSON object, so it will just save it as a standard string